# Use QUERY to select values from Sheet based on current time in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to use a Google Sheet that displays the current delivery times based on the times during the day. I am accessing the current time with `now()` and then need to pull the data in from another sheet with QUERY if the current time is between the time slots. Here is the QUERY I am working with that isn't working at the moment:

=query(TimeSlots!B:B, "select B where A contains '"&A2&"'")

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vPszopGlUx34RLKOmD6qOoDJPrgoYq8XClsGfY9zRvE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See if this works

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(timevalue(A2), {iferror(value(regexextract(TimeSlots!A2:A, "(.+)\s-"))),TimeSlots!B2:C}, {2, 3}, 1))
```